# update in ms access using c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, insert-update

can someone please help what is wrong with my code?
it is a update function and during my debug it executing properly but it is not updating my database.
I already search for an answer to for this problem but still it didn't work.
i also try to create a new database hoping that it is problem but still no effect.

```
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\sherilyn & justine\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\jollibee4\jollibee4\jollibee.accdb";
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
String id = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + String.Empty;
int id1 = Int32.Parse(id);
try
{
if (database.selectedIndex == 0)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Breakfast_Meals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 1)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Burger_Sandwhich_Meals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 2)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Chicken_Meals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 3)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Dessert set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 4)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Kids_Meals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 5)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update RiceMeals_NoodlesMeals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 6)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Side_Items set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
else if (database.selectedIndex == 7)
{
cmd.CommandText = "update Value_Meals set [Meals] = @meals, [Price] = @price, [Picture] = @picture, [Description] = @description WHERE [Item ID]=@id";
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meals", meal.Text);
int mealPrice = Int32.Parse(price.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", mealPrice);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", savePhoto());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",description.Text);
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to change the data?","Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
con.Close();
}
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
database_onItemSelected(sender, e);//to view dgv data for the selected index
con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
con.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: eep.  so not minimal viable example.. Ok.. so. what happens when you trace it, does it run the update command..

Comment: when i try to put breakpoint it goes to the `ExecuteNonQuery()` so I think it means that my update it successful but after viewing my database it still not updated

Answer (score 2):

Add the parameters in the correct order as expected by the placeholders

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meals", meal.Text);
int mealPrice = Int32.Parse(price.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", mealPrice);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", savePhoto());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",description.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id1);
```

OleDb doesn't resolve parameters values by their name, but by the parameter's position in the parameters collection. With your order the *id* condition in the where clause receives the value from the description parameter.

Consider also to use Add instead of AddWithValue

See: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I didn't expect that it is the cause of my problem. but it works now. thank you :)

Comment: Will put my hand up, Id not have expected the order to matter.